# SyntaxError when runing "python examples/train.py singleagent_ring"

Tags: python, sumo, flow-project, rllib

[image]

When I run `python examples/train.py singleagent_ring`
I find the following error:

```
file "examples/train.py", line 201
    **config
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please any help?

Comment: Would you mind adding the mentioned line of code from you script to your question? Then the community can help you better!

Comment: i just added it, you can see it please

Comment: welcome to SO. avoid pasting code as images as others cannot reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I feel like if you added the code you were working on as well as well as the line of code where the error was found that would make this question easier to understand. Additionally, have you attempted to debug this issue on your own? If so, what did you try? Informing us of these things would make it much easier to get the full picture of the issue you've encountered.

Aside from that, a SyntaxError is usually associated with something being mistyped in the syntax of your code so you may want to look it over for any spelling errors, missing indents, and/or missing/extra characters in your code. That's the most I or anyone else here can really tell you without any more context.